# Flutter plugin not working after update Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, plugins, flutter-plugin, android-studio-plugin

I updated Android studio to the latest version but unfortunately, After the update some plugins were disabled
flutter plugin is one of them
Flutter "`Incompatible (Since build 203.6682.168 > AI-202.7660.26.42.7486908)`".

```
Flutter version (60.1.2)
```

And no update option

[image]

I updated the dart plugin but there is no update for flutter available right now.

Comment: Maybe raise an issue in the plugin github repo could get you feedback from the authors